# ios detecting line angle or degree

Tags: iphone, ios, drawing, uibezierpath

I'm new to **iOS**, i am trying to develop a freehand drawing app, using `uibezierPath`.is there a way to calculate or receive the total line length, even if i drew straight line, curved or a circle. 
i am using addline on the the touchmove method, and i don't have any control points.

Answer (score 8):

Inside your `touchesBegan` method, you can use this code

```
{
UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint present = [touch locationInView:self];
CGPoint previous = [touch previousLocationInView:self];
CGFloat angle = [self getAngle:present :previous];
}

- (float) getAngle:(CGPoint)a :(CGPoint)b
{
    int x = a.x;
    int y = a.y;
    float dx = b.x - x;
    float dy = b.y - y;
    CGFloat radians = atan2(-dx,dy);        // in radians
    CGFloat degrees = radians * 180 / 3.14; // in degrees
    return angle;
}
```

You can call this method in any method to find the angle between two `CGPoints` in the `UIView`.

Hope this helped :-)

Comment: Thanks, now, if i am drawing a line  using touchesbegan and touchesmove How can I get the length of the line between those two points?

Comment: yes this give me straight line between to points, and if its a circle the two points end at the same place, how can i get the length of the line if its a curve one, rectangle or a circle?

Comment: @CharlesD'Monte Great answer! It helped me a lot in answering a different question...but there are a few issues... The "radians" formula's not quite right, you're returning "angle" instead of "degrees" and the answer also doesn't account for the fact that `atan2` can return either a positive or negative radian. Also it's probably best to replace 3.14 with M_PI so as not to lose so many digits.

Comment: Here's a link to how I adapted this question to handle a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27759584/2274694

Comment: return degrees;

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of whether the line is curved or straight, you can find the distance between any two points. (I don't know how to get the length of the line). If the line is straight, the distance between the two points should be equal to that of the line.

Try this code,

```
- (double)getDistance:(CGPoint)one :(CGPoint)two
{
    return sqrt((two.x - one.x)*(two.x - one.x) + (two.y - one.y)*(two.y - one.y));
}
```

It's a common method many are familiar with, (sqrt)[(x2-x1)*(x2-x1) + (y2-y1)*(y2-y1)].

Hope this helps :-)