# Define touch areas - objective-c

Tags: objective-c, touch, touchesbegan

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27759116/ios-derive-angle-of-tap-point-given-a-circle) ingenious solution in stackoverflow. Unfortunately, this code does not work in my project. I try to divide a round SKSpriteNode in four different touch areas. I would also like to change the color of the area (Only when the area is pressed). Do you know perhaps how to do that?

For an example, or help I am very grateful.

My code:

```
- (void)setUpDPad {  
    _dPad = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"dpad"];
    _dPad.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
    _dPad.position = CGPointMake(0.0-self.frame.size.width/2+5, 0.0-self.frame.size.height/2+50);
    _dPad.zPosition = 1;
    [self addChild:_dPad];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {

        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
        CGFloat angle = [self angleToPoint:location];
        int area = [self sectionForAngle:angle];

        if ([_dPad containsPoint:location]) {
            if (area == 1) {

            }
            if (area == 2) {

            }
            if (area == 3) {

            }
            if (area == 4) {

            }
       }
    }
}

- (float)angleToPoint:(CGPoint)tapPoint {

    int x = _dPad.frame.size.width/2;
    int y = _dPad.frame.size.height/2;
    float dx = tapPoint.x - x;
    float dy = tapPoint.y - y;
    CGFloat radians = atan2(dy,dx);
    CGFloat degrees = radians * 180 / M_PI;

    if (degrees < 0) return fabs(degrees);
    else return 360 - degrees;
}

- (int)sectionForAngle:(float)angle {

    if (angle >= 45 && angle < 135) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (angle >= 135 && angle < 225) {
        return 2;
    }
    else if (angle >= 225 && angle < 315) {
        return 3;
    }
    else {
        return 4;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt to debug your problem, or do you expect others to do your work for you?

Comment: @Avi I do not know where is the problem with the code abow. I tryed a lot of things but It does not work. That is why I ask the stackoverflow comunity. Maybe someone can help me.